# I'm building a simple Android app but my if statement isn't functioning as intended and I'm not sure why?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and Android development but not new to programming in general. I'm working on a very simple basic calculator to help me get familiar with programming on Android. For the most part, things are going well but I'm having trouble understanding why my following code isn't working as intended.

My code should read the string held in the TextView "`display` in the code" and check if it's blank, ends in a number, or ends in a symbol. It successfully can tell if the TextView is blank. When adding a second number or symbol it goes to the if statement that says, "Ends in Number",  but when adding, or trying to add another number or symbol it will default to the else if: "Ends in symbol adding number", and stay there no matter what I click. I don't have it specifically checking for symbols because if it doesn't end in a number than it can only end in a symbol, so my code reflects that by checking to see if the string ends in a number.

Each number 1-9, and the symbols, on the app are set with OnClickListener to call the addToDisplay function.

As far as I can tell my code should read the string and see if it ends in a number or symbol, and so long as symbols are not placed back to back should add to the TextView. Clearly, I'm not fully understanding my code because as much as I think I've written it right it's not working so I clearly misunderstood something. I would very much appreciate anyone able to help me understand what I'm doing wrong, thank you!

*******CODE*******

```
fun addToDisplay(toAdd: String, display : TextView){
    val symbols = Regex("[-./+*]$") // The $ makes this check the end of a string for these symbols
        val numbers = Regex("[0-9]$")
        // Takes the string passed in and appends it to the textview.
        if (display.text.isEmpty()){
            // If display is empty
            if(!symbols.matches(toAdd)){
                // Adds to the display as long as it's not a symbol defined above.
                display.append(toAdd)
                println("Empty display")
            }
        } else {

            if (numbers.matches(display.text)) {
                display.append(toAdd)
                println(display.text)
                println("Ends in number")
            } else if (numbers.matches(toAdd)) {
                // Pattern NOT recognizing numbers
                display.append(toAdd)
                println(display.text)
                println(numbers.matches(display.text))
                println("Ends in symbol and adding number")
            }
        }
    }// End addToDisplay
```

Comment: "My code should read the string held in the TextView and check if it's blank, ends in a number, or ends in a symbol" -- what is "the TextView"? If "the TextView` is `display`, then you are not doing what you wrote in that sentence. You have `display.text.isEmpty()` to see if it is empty. You have `numbers.matches(display.text)` to see if it ends in a number. You have nothing to see if it ends in a symbol.

Comment: The TextView is display, sorry about not clarifying that properly. My program can only end in numbers or symbols, so if it doesn't end in a number it has to be a symbol, that was my thought process as I wrote this bit of code

Comment: Rewrite your code such that this is a testable function (e.g., it takes a `String` as input and returns a `String` as output). Write some unit tests for your various scenarios. For a failing test, such as the scenario that you are in, use the debugger and breakpoints to step through your code to see where you are going wrong.

Comment: Ok so after checking things more it seems like my issue may come from my 'regex' expression. I only learned about those the other day and my understanding of them is very shallow. It seems like I may be using those wrong and the if statement isn't actually the problem. I still haven't been able to get it to work, but I think I'm on the right track to figuring it out.

Comment: Your `symbols` regex seems like it is using `-` to indicate the subtraction operator symbol. In Java regular expression syntax, `-` is used to indicate a range of characters, like are you are doing in `numbers`. So, you probably need to escape that (e.g., `Regex("[\\-./+*]$")`). FWIW, I find [this site](https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) to be useful for playing around with regular expressions to see if they behave as I expect.

Comment: Thanks, I think that may have been my issue. Also thanks for that site, it's going to be very helpful!